# Outlook 2003 not working with GMail IMAP

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap, microsoft-outlook-2003

I am trying to configure Outlook Express 2003 with GMail (IMAP enabled)

However my Outlook is giving me this error:

[image: ScreenShot of Error]

How can I rectify this problem?

Comment: Could you be behind a firewall that blocks access to Gmail's IMAP port? Gmail uses non-standard ports for IMAP and POP3, so your firewall may be blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Thunderbird, but maybe this will help you: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=75291

Comment: But, google suggests to go with IMAP instead of POP.

Answer (score 0):

> Have you enabled IMAP in Gmail?
>   Sign in to the Gmail web interface. Open the 'Forwarding and POP/IMAP' tab on your 'Settings' page, and configure IMAP. After enabling IMAP in Gmail, make sure you click 'Save Changes' so Gmail can communicate with your mail client.

From Gmail FAQ.